# Can you create a javascript function on an event handler?

Tags: javascript, function, events, call, handler

can you call a javascript function on event handlers? What I mean is like,

```
... onClick="dosomething()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosomething(){alert("I just did something");}
```

the code isn't complete but i've tried it this way all nice and neat and it doesn't work, does this mean we have to enter the whole JS code inside the event handler???

Comment: Yes, you can. If you're not able to, then the problem is elsewhere unfortunately.

Comment: Of course you can. You should have tried it.

Comment: what you have should work, perhaps you can show little more of your code. The problem most likely lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the event handler without specifying it inline.  If you know the id of the element its pretty simple.

**Javascript**

```
function doSomething(){
   alert("I just did something");
}

var elem = document.getElementById("idGoesHere");
elem.onclick = function(){
    doSomething();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="idGoesHere">Click Me</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DYqjA/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=function(){dosomething()};
function dosomething(){alert("I just did something");}
</script>
```

Crude example using JavaScript

Comment: alright so this is the whole code, i want to do the function elsewhere, not write the whole thing inside the event handler:

Comment: that is the event handler, plus a separately defined function which is called from the event handler. This is the handler: `document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=function(){dosomething()};`, which instructs the client to execute the function `dosomething()` when it detects an element with the id `myBtn` is clicked. The `dosomething()` function can be placed wherever you like, and can include any or as much code as you like. Hope this helps clarify